# How to capture parentheses only when escaped?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm defining a regex as follows:

```
regex = new Regex(@"^\(([^()]+)\)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This has been useful for processing content like this:

```
abc
123
(xyz)
some things
(more of the other)
```

and returning group 1 matches for:

```
xyz
more of the other
```

However, when it encounters text like this:

```
abc
123
(xyz)
some things
(111 \(look at this\) 999)
(more of the other)
```

I want it to match

```
xyz
111 \(look at this\) 999
more of the other
```

But I can't figure out how to modify the character class `[^()]` to indicate that parentheses are acceptable when escaped with a preceding "\".  I tried:

```
^\((([^()]|\\\(|\\\))+)\)
```

But the group 1 matches for this are:

```
xyz
111 \(look at this\
more of the other
```

Note the missing closing parenthesis in the second match.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that there can be text following a parenthesis group, which should not be captured, e.g.:

```
(more of the other) TB ff
```

should only capture

```
more of the other
```

Comment: show your code, in particular the string you use for the pattern.

Comment: Can there be any `(`, ``\\`` or `\(` in *outside*  the `(...)`?

Comment: So, you want to match all text between an `(` and a `)` that isn't preceded by a backslash?

Comment: Why not just `^\(.*?\)$` ? Would match everything between the brackets if they are defining the start and end of the line.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I want to match all text between unescaped `(` and `)`, including escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude the backslash from the character class otherwise the second and third branches will not match the escape character first. To allow other characters to be escaped too, you need to replace parenthesis with a dot:

```
\(((?>(?:[^()\\]|\\.)+))\)
```

You can also write it like this (more efficient):

```
\(((?>[^()\\]*(?:\\.[^()\\]*)*))\)
```

Comment: This approach won't work for strings like [`\(111 \(look at this\) 999)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5c%5c%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%5c.%5b%5e%28%29%5c%5c%5d*%29*%29%29%5c%29&i=%5c%28111+%5c%28look+at+this%5c%29+999%29).

Answer (score 1):

Why not keeping it simple?

```
^\((.+)\)$
```

This matches everything between `(` and `)` if they define the beginning and end of a line.
Example: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PUfNu3/2)

Dont forget to set multiline-mode.

---

Input:

```
(111 \(look at this\) 999)
(more of the other)
abc
123
(xyz)
some things
```

Results:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-26    `(111 \(look at this\) 999)`
Group 1.    1-25    `111 \(look at this\) 999`
Match 2
Full match  27-46   `(more of the other)`
Group 1.    28-45   `more of the other`
Match 3
Full match  55-60   `(xyz)`
Group 1.    56-59   `xyz`
```

Comment: There is potentially text after the end of the closing parenthesis, e.g. `(more of the other) TB ff`