# Exclude an escaped character from a range

Tags: regex

I need to extract an expression between brackets that can include everything but not an non-escaped closed bracket.

For example, the regexp from `[aaa\]bbbbbb]` should give as result : `aaa\]bbbbbb`.

I tried this : `\[([^(?<!\\)\]]*)\]`  but that fail.

Any hints?

Comment: Awesome, thanks ! I will get some time to understand the explanation from the tool page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\[([^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*)]
```

Or  - if there may be any non-escaped `[` in-between non-escaped `[` and `]` (e.g. `[a[\[aa\]bbbbbba\[aabbbbbb]`), take out the `\[`:

```
 \[([^\]\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\\]*)*)]
```

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/47aWMD/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hbJqf1/1). It is an [unrolled variant](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) of a [`\[((?:[^][\\]|\\.)*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/47aWMD/2) regex.

**Details**:

- `\[` - a `[`
- `([^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `[^\]\[\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `\` (in some regex flavors, you may write it without escapes - `[^][\\]*`)
  - `(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\\.` - any escaped sequence (`\` and any char other than line break chars
    - `[^\]\[\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `\`
- `]` -  a closing `]`.

Comment: Your regex will fail against something like `[a[\[aa\]bbbbbba\[aabbbbbb]` (with another opening bracket inside the brackets)

Comment: @Aserre: Sure, because the unescaped `[` and `]` are not balanced. It is not mentioned what the behavior should be for these scenarios in OP.

Comment: `I need to extract an expression between brackets that can include everything but not an non-escaped closed bracket.`  :)

Comment: @Aserre: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40840551/3832970), I posted the same comment to the similar answer. A regex like this will only work with a properly formatted string. Otherwise, some smart parsing code is required, but OP has not indicated the language. Also, a [`\[([^\]\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\\]*)*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/47aWMD/3) might work better in certain scenarios. I added this option to the answer. In most cases, these `[` inside `[...]` are not expected though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to be more specific, i meant "I need to extract an expression between brackets that can include everything but not an non-escaped bracket."

Comment: Ok, so the second expression should work for *you*, right? If you need to be able to match line breaks, too, either replace `.` with `[\s\S]` or use the DOTALL/Singleline/`s` modifier (in Ruby, it is `/m` modifier).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest regex that (I think) works:

```
\[(.*?)(?<!\\)\]
```

which captures the bracketed text as group 1.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/PtFQlpKtjW).